# Create a AWS Lambda API Gateway and Lambda Function by API

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to use AWS API Gateway and AWS Lambda(Python) for serving some static request. My use case requires me to create an API Gateway and lambda function once a setting is saved in my web application.

I was wondering if there is a way to create API Gateway and Lambda Function by API.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can use the Amazon Console to create Lambda functions and API Gateways.

Review the Amazon Console documentation.

[Working with the AWS Management Console](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsconsolehelpdocs/latest/gsg/getting-started.html)

[Getting Started Guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsconsolehelpdocs/latest/gsg/console-help-gsg.pdf)

Review the API Gateway and Lambda Python SDKs:

[APIGateway](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/apigateway.html)

[Lambda](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/lambda.html)

Comment: I have done it by using Amazon Console. I wanted to know if there is a way wherein i can create it without using the console.

Comment: Read the SDK documentation links that I included in my answer. By using the SDK you can do just about anything with Amazon services.

Comment: Thanks John ... let me take a look

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using the API, I strongly suggest that you look into The Serverless Framework. It does all of the heavy lifting for you, allowing you to focus on the code, and your business specific logic.

https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/quick-start/

This link shows a quickstart guide to deploying a Hello World Lambda and API Gateway resources. The more I use the framework the more I like it :)